# Spawn network objects in generated map

Tags: unity, multiplayer, procedural-generation, synchronization, unet

In my game, the server generates a procedural map, after send generation seed to generate it on the client. The client generates exactly the same map. In the map, I need to synchronize objects with NetworkIdentity. Therefore, after the map is generated on clients, the server will spawn all map's objects with NetworkIdentity on the client using NetworkServer.Spawn on server. In theory, it sounds normal, but in practice, objects on the server that have a NetworkIdentity component can not be obtained with GetChild from the object of the generated map. Unity do not see them. This probably means that they are not active on the server. How to fix it? And if it will fix, will the objects with NetworkIdentity be spawned on the client as children of the map? If this is not possible, is it possible to use something other than the UNET?

That's what I did:

On start server:

```
public static short index = 0;
public const int getGenIndex = 99; // OnGetGen
public const int spawnGenIndex = 100; // OnSpawnGeneration
public const int spawnObjIndex = 101; // OnSpawnNetworkObjects

private void Start() {
    if (isServer)
        NetworkServer.SpawnObjects();
    if (isServer) {
        GenerationInfo generation = InitScane.instance.GetGeneration(InitScane.rnd.Next()); // generate map
        InitScane.instance.seedToSpawn = InitScane.rnd.Next();
        GenerationManager.SpawnGeneration(RoomLoader.loadedRooms, generation, InitScane.instance.seedToSpawn, true); // spawn map on server with objects
        NetworkServer.SendToAll(spawnGenIndex,new StringMessage(GenerationManager.currentGeneration.Seed + "," + InitScane.instance.seedToSpawn)); // send message for spawn on client
    }
    else
        NetworkManager.singleton.client.Send(getGenIndex, new EmptyMessage()); // the client requests the seed to generate the map  
}

public void OnGetGen(NetworkMessage msg){
    msg.conn.Send(spawnGenIndex,new StringMessage(GenerationManager.currentGeneration.Seed + "," + InitScane.instance.seedToSpawn));
}

public void OnSpawnGeneration(NetworkMessage msg) {
    string[] data = msg.ReadMessage<StringMessage>().value.Split(',');
    GenerationInfo generation = InitScane.instance.GetGeneration(int.Parse(data[0])); // generate map
    GenerationManager.SpawnGeneration(RoomLoader.loadedRooms, generation, int.Parse(data[1]), false); // spawn map without objects with NetworkIdentity
    msg.conn.Send(spawnObjIndex, new EmptyMessage()); // send request for spawn objects with NetworkIdentity and spawn player
}

public void OnSpawnNetworkObjects(NetworkMessage msg) {
    GenerationManager.SendAllObjectsToClients();
    GameObject player = Instantiate(InitScane.instance.LocalPlayer);
    GenerationManager.TeleportPlayerToStart(player);
    NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(msg.conn, player, index);
    index++;
}
```

All network message I register in Awake on client and server. This is how I spawn objects for clients:

```
public static GenerationInfo currentGeneration;
    private static GameObject[,] spawnedRooms; // the map consists of many rooms that are separate GameObjects

    public static void SendAllObjectsToClients() {
        for(int x = 0; x < currentGeneration.size.x; x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < currentGeneration.size.y; y++)
                SendObjects(spawnedRooms[x, y]);
    }

    public static void SendObjects(GameObject roomObject) {
        Transform objectParent = roomObject.transform.Find("Objects"); // all room objects are stored in the parent "Objects"
        for (int i = 0; i < objectParent.childCount; i++)
            if (objectParent.GetChild(i).GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>() != null)
                NetworkServer.Spawn(objectParent.GetChild(i).gameObject);
    }
```

The latter method does not find objects with NetworkIdentity, although they are spawned in the editor. If you put them to the array when spawning, they will turn into null

Comment: if you already have a list or array of the objects that you use to spawn all those on the map you should be able to use that to loop through and get a ref to the object and NetworkIdentity on each one that way instead of using GetChild from the object map..

Comment: @JustinMarkwell Even if I add these objects to the list immediately after spawn, they will be null

Comment: Can you provide some code? It might help us understand the the problem a little better (And welcome to Stack.GD!)

Comment: @Stephan I updated the question, I added the code